# How does this binary encoder function work?

Tags: binary-data, categorical-data, dummy-variable, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to understand the logic behind this binary encoder.

It automatically takes categorical variables and dummy codes them (similar to one-hot-encoding on sklearn), but reduces the number of output columns equal to the log2 of the length of unique values.

Basically, when I used this library, I noticed that my dummy variables are limited to only a few of the unique values. Upon further investigation I noticed this `@staticmethod`, which take the log2 of the len of unique values in a categorical variable.

My question is WHY? I realize that this reduces the dimensionality of the output data, but what is the logic behind doing this? How does taking the log2 determine how many digits are needed to represent the data?

```
 def calc_required_digits(X, col):
        """
        figure out how many digits we need to represent the classes present
        """
        return int( np.ceil(np.log2(len(X[col].unique()))) )
```

Full source code:

```
"""Binary encoding"""

import copy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from category_encoders.ordinal import OrdinalEncoder
from category_encoders.utils import get_obj_cols, convert_input

__author__ = 'willmcginnis'


[docs]class BinaryEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Binary encoding for categorical variables, similar to onehot, but stores categories as binary bitstrings.

    Parameters
    ----------

    verbose: int
        integer indicating verbosity of output. 0 for none.
    cols: list
        a list of columns to encode, if None, all string columns will be encoded
    drop_invariant: bool
        boolean for whether or not to drop columns with 0 variance
    return_df: bool
        boolean for whether to return a pandas DataFrame from transform (otherwise it will be a numpy array)
    impute_missing: bool
        boolean for whether or not to apply the logic for handle_unknown, will be deprecated in the future.
    handle_unknown: str
        options are 'error', 'ignore' and 'impute', defaults to 'impute', which will impute the category -1. Warning: if
        impute is used, an extra column will be added in if the transform matrix has unknown categories.  This can causes
        unexpected changes in dimension in some cases.

    Example
    -------
    >>>from category_encoders import *
    >>>import pandas as pd
    >>>from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
    >>>bunch = load_boston()
    >>>y = bunch.target
    >>>X = pd.DataFrame(bunch.data, columns=bunch.feature_names)
    >>>enc = BinaryEncoder(cols=['CHAS', 'RAD']).fit(X, y)
    >>>numeric_dataset = enc.transform(X)
    >>>print(numeric_dataset.info())

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 506 entries, 0 to 505
    Data columns (total 16 columns):
    CHAS_0     506 non-null int64
    RAD_0      506 non-null int64
    RAD_1      506 non-null int64
    RAD_2      506 non-null int64
    RAD_3      506 non-null int64
    CRIM       506 non-null float64
    ZN         506 non-null float64
    INDUS      506 non-null float64
    NOX        506 non-null float64
    RM         506 non-null float64
    AGE        506 non-null float64
    DIS        506 non-null float64
    TAX        506 non-null float64
    PTRATIO    506 non-null float64
    B          506 non-null float64
    LSTAT      506 non-null float64
    dtypes: float64(11), int64(5)
    memory usage: 63.3 KB
    None

    """
    def __init__(self, verbose=0, cols=None, drop_invariant=False, return_df=True, impute_missing=True, handle_unknown='impute'):
        self.return_df = return_df
        self.drop_invariant = drop_invariant
        self.drop_cols = []
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.impute_missing = impute_missing
        self.handle_unknown = handle_unknown
        self.cols = cols
        self.ordinal_encoder = None
        self._dim = None
        self.digits_per_col = {}

[docs]    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        """Fit encoder according to X and y.

        Parameters
        ----------

        X : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
            Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples
            and n_features is the number of features.
        y : array-like, shape = [n_samples]
            Target values.

        Returns
        -------

        self : encoder
            Returns self.

        """

        # if the input dataset isn't already a dataframe, convert it to one (using default column names)
        # first check the type
        X = convert_input(X)

        self._dim = X.shape[1]

        # if columns aren't passed, just use every string column
        if self.cols is None:
            self.cols = get_obj_cols(X)

        # train an ordinal pre-encoder
        self.ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder(
            verbose=self.verbose,
            cols=self.cols,
            impute_missing=self.impute_missing,
            handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown
        )
        self.ordinal_encoder = self.ordinal_encoder.fit(X)

        for col in self.cols:
            self.digits_per_col[col] = self.calc_required_digits(X, col)

        # drop all output columns with 0 variance.
        if self.drop_invariant:
            self.drop_cols = []
            X_temp = self.transform(X)
            self.drop_cols = [x for x in X_temp.columns.values if X_temp[x].var() <= 10e-5]



        return self


[docs]    def transform(self, X):
        """Perform the transformation to new categorical data.

        Parameters
        ----------

        X : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]

        Returns
        -------

        p : array, shape = [n_samples, n_numeric + N]
            Transformed values with encoding applied.

        """

        if self._dim is None:
            raise ValueError('Must train encoder before it can be used to transform data.')

        # first check the type
        X = convert_input(X)

        # then make sure that it is the right size
        if X.shape[1] != self._dim:
            raise ValueError('Unexpected input dimension %d, expected %d' % (X.shape[1], self._dim, ))

        if not self.cols:
            return X

        X = self.ordinal_encoder.transform(X)

        X = self.binary(X, cols=self.cols)

        if self.drop_invariant:
            for col in self.drop_cols:
                X.drop(col, 1, inplace=True)

        if self.return_df:
            return X
        else:
            return X.values


[docs]    def binary(self, X_in, cols=None):
        """
        Binary encoding encodes the integers as binary code with one column per digit.
        """

        X = X_in.copy(deep=True)

        if cols is None:
            cols = X.columns.values
            pass_thru = []
        else:
            pass_thru = [col for col in X.columns.values if col not in cols]

        bin_cols = []
        for col in cols:
            # get how many digits we need to represent the classes present
            digits = self.digits_per_col[col]

            # map the ordinal column into a list of these digits, of length digits
            X[col] = X[col].map(lambda x: self.col_transform(x, digits))

            for dig in range(digits):
                X[str(col) + '_%d' % (dig, )] = X[col].map(lambda r: int(r[dig]) if r is not None else None)
                bin_cols.append(str(col) + '_%d' % (dig, ))

        X = X.reindex(columns=bin_cols + pass_thru)

        return X


[docs]    @staticmethod
    def calc_required_digits(X, col):
        """
        figure out how many digits we need to represent the classes present
        """
        return int( np.ceil(np.log2(len(X[col].unique()))) )




[docs]    @staticmethod
    def col_transform(col, digits):
        """
        The lambda body to transform the column values
        """

        if col is None or float(col) < 0.0:
            return None
        else:

            col = list("{0:b}".format(int(col)))
            if len(col) == digits:
                return col
            else:
                return [0 for _ in range(digits - len(col))] + col
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is WHY? I realize that this reduces the dimensionality of
>   the output data, but what is the logic behind doing this?

Basically, the issue of categorical encoding is to make your algorithm it's dealing with categorical features. Therefore, several methods are available for doing it, including binary encoding. Actually, it's logic is close to the logic of One Hot Encoding (OHE), if you understood it.

For binary encoding, each unique label in your categorical vector is associated randomly to a number between (0) and (the number of unique labels-1). Now, you encode this number in base 2 and "transcript" the previous number in 0 and 1 through the newly created columns.
As an example, let's say your dataset as three different labels: 'A', 'B' & 'C'.
The following correspondance is randomly built:

'A' -> 1 -> 01;

'B' -> 2 > 10;

'C' -> 0 -> 00.

Therefore, an example of encoding of a given dataset is:

index my_category enc_category_0 enc_category_1

0     A,         1,         0

1,     B,         0,         1

2,     C,         0,         0

3     A,         1,         0

Regarding the utility of it, as you said it's reduce the dimensionality. Besides, I guess it helps not having too much zeros in the encoded columns as with OHE. Here is an interesting post: https://medium.com/data-design/visiting-categorical-features-and-encoding-in-decision-trees-53400fa65931

> How does taking the log2 determine how many digits are needed to represent the data?
>   If you understood the working principle, you understand the use of the log2. Computing the log2 of a number retrives the necessary number of digits for a binary encoding of this number. Example: [log2(10)]=[3.32]=4, 4 digits are needed for binary encode 10.

For more info about the implementation and code example: http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/_modules/category_encoders/binary.html#BinaryEncoder

Hope I was clear,

Tchau